# How can I force sphinx-apidoc to generate doc using my own rst templates?

Tags: python, templates, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I generate documentation by sphinx-apidoc. Documentation is genereted to default rst templates. How can I generate documentation with my own rst templates?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/ef3092d458cc00c4b74dd342ea05ba1059a5da70/sphinx/apidoc.py?at=default), it looks like they don't actually have a formal template. However, the script does seem simple enough to modify. See the `create_*_file` methods.